# MySQL variables change, takes no effect

Tags: mysql

I have set these variables in my 'my.ini' file :

```
[mysqld] 
ft_min_word_len = 1 
max_allowed_packet = 1073741824 
max_connections = 250 
connect_timeout = 10
```

In MySQL Workbench I can see that the values are set.

But if I run this query for example in MySQL Workbench

```
 SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

I got this result:

Variable_name: **max_allowed_packet**

Value: **4194304**

So the value is not properly set.

Also the `ft_min_word_len` is still 4, as default value, not 1 as is set.

Can you tell me what I must do?!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you re-started the mysql server after doing the changes ?

Comment: yes i restart the server and rebuild the tables

Comment: Did you check that you changed the correct my.ini?

Comment: @Jimmy T. I have reinstalled my MySql, now it works. The misstake was, that i have override my default 'my.ini' and the MySQL-Service could't find that file...Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to set value from mysql terminal

```
set global max_allowed_packet='1073741824 '
```